Story about two long haul spacecraft traveling parallel
I can't find the name of this story, any help is appreciated. It has two long haul spacecraft traveling parallel. Each is mostly self-sufficient with a small crew. The story is about the events during their travels. One event I recall was the antenna array failing on one ship and a spacewalk by members of the other ship to fix it. There was a lot of hostility between crew members on one of the ships. I believe it was from the last decade or so of writing. Thanks in advance.

Why can't the one crew fix their own craft?  It seems a lot simpler than trying to cross between two different ships.

Somehow this makes me think of Bear's Hull Zero Three.

Antenna array failing on one ship and a spacewalk [...] to fix it? Somehow this makes me think of 2001. HAL's not your pal, Dave!

@DavidW: My guess would be that it involves parts/personnel that only the other ship had. I could see that even becoming a point of tension, that the one ship was "better prepared" even if the only ship was only lacking due to mishap.

Your details are rather scant but there is a chance this is Chasm City by Alastair Reynolds published in 2001 (slightly earlier than your time frame but could match)
One of the several plot strands features a convoy of sleeper ships. There is rivalry between ships and also friction between crew members of the ship we follow most closely. There is also a scene in which a crew make a repair outside their ship only to be killed in an accident.
There is a wikipedia page here...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasm_City
although it does not go into detail on this particular plot strand.

While it's not mentioned in detail in the Wikipedia article, the details that @skyjack are referring do happen in the form of a sort of "flashback" induced by the cited "melding plague" from the article.  These "flashbacks" take up a substantial portion of the book.
